# Is Linkedin, Google and Facebook Running BitTorrent client?

Tags: appsec, bittorrent

I'm running a application classification program which detects the application based on training datasets and signatures. I'm getting a alert of BitTorrent is running on my system but the application is not installed on my system. Actually it is classifying BitTorrent based on the destination port used 6881, Since 6881 is used by BitTorrent. The destination which is shown in the alert is related to Facebook domain. See the below reverse nslookup result

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

**C:\Users\rpmishra>nslookup 173.252.120.6

Server:  "servername"

Address:  "ip"

Name:    edge-star-shv-12-frc3.facebook.com

Address:  173.252.120.6**

[image: Application alert image]

Also I have captured the packets in wireshark and analyzed every packet when FB, Google and Linkedin was running but I didn't found the port 6881 and other BitTorrent patterns. So how is it possible that IPs are related to these services ?

Comment: Could you run netstat and see which process is talking to this address?

Comment: Already ran the netstat command there is no such IP and port combination.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce or identify what fired this packet then?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce it but no success. Is it possible that the applications running in the facebook can use these ports ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is:

No, Linkedin, Google and Facebook are not running a BitTorrent client

If your sensor is triggering only on the use of port 6881, then it could be set off by anything that uses that port. As most applications dynamically assign ports, this could explain why you haven't managed to recreate it.

The solutions:

- Don't use a sensor that works solely by matching port
- Limit applications to specific port ranges

Comment: That's true but I don't know how they are matching their rules means they are ORing or ANDin the rule. If they are classifying based on port then that is bad practice.